# Rerendering the same UI more times

Tags: shiny

I have this simple shiny app with two action buttons. The "Render" button renders a slider input control while the "Remove" button removes the same slider input. This works fine the first time but trying to rerender the same slider input the second time does not work. Any idea or explanation what may be wrong with the code?

This is the code:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
            actionButton("render", "Render"),
            actionButton("remove", "Remove"),
            uiOutput("moreControls")
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
            observeEvent(input$render, {
                    if (input$render > 0) {
                            output$moreControls <- renderUI({
                                    tagList(
                                            sliderInput("n", "N", 1, 1000, 500)
                                    )
                            })    
                    }
            })
            observeEvent(input$remove, {
                    if (input$remove > 0) {
                            removeUI(
                                    selector = "div[id='moreControls']"
                            )
                    }
            })

    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the control to NULL to remove it. See code.

```
library(shiny)  

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("render", "Render"),
  actionButton("remove", "Remove"),
  uiOutput("moreControls")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  rv <- reactiveValues() 

  observeEvent(input$render, { rv$action <- 'render' })
  observeEvent(input$remove, { rv$action <- 'remove' }) 

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({ 

    if (is.null(rv$action)) {return(NULL)} 

    if(rv$action == 'render'){ 
      sliderInput(inputId = "n",label =  "N", min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)    
    } else {  
      return(NULL)
    } 
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanky for the answer. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: removeUI removes the slider, it cannot be updated. You may generate a new one with insertUI.

Comment: What confuses me it that I am using renderUI not updateUI to rerender the slider. Your solution works but I cannot explain to myself way my code does not work...

Comment: See 3.execution in http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/cheatsheet.html. output$moreControls is run once at app init. Code inside output$moreControls will be run ‘often’.

Comment: Need some time to get that. I thought the putting renderUI inside observeEvent would make it run 'often'. I still don't get it but thank you anyway...